# Replace Customer_city based on Sales Value

Tags: pandas, group-by

I have a task

1. Find same customer_state column in the  merged_df and city_df and replace customer_city in the merged_df with city in the city_df based population size matching quantity_of_sales in merged_df.
2. The biggest quantity sales should have the largest population cities

Code
# Merge merged_df with City_df based on the 'State' column
merged_state_df = pd.merge(merged_df, City_df[['city', 'State']], on='State', how='left')

```
# Sort df_sorted by '2020' column in descending order
= df_sorted.sort_values(by='2020', ascending=False)

# Iterate over each group of customers in the same state
for state, group in merged_state_df.groupby('customer_state'):
# Find the city with the largest quantity_of_sales from df_sorted
largest_city = df_sorted_descending[df_sorted_descending['State'] == state].iloc[0]['city']

# Update the 'customer_city' in the merged DataFrame with the largest city
merged_state_df.loc[group.index, 'customer_city'] = largest_city

# Display the updated merged DataFrame
print(merged_state_df.head())
```

Error Message
File "", line 13
mergered_state_df.loc[group.index, 'customer_city'] = largest_city
^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

Does anyone what is wrong with my code

[image]
[image]

1. Find same customer_state column in the  merged_df and City_df  and replace customer_city in the merged_df with city in the City_df based in quantity_of_sales in merged_df.
2. The biggest quantity sales should have the largest population cities (column name 2020)

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1grJ9GzRmF3gPu7t-H9p2mw1tS7zyjDLo?usp=sharing

Comment: for IndentationError: , check the 2 lines of code below the for loop there are out of the loop due to which you are getting IndentationError , you need to put it under for loop.

Comment: Could you help elaborate more please?

Comment: @VanessaMiranda publish small samples of your dataframes so they can be reproduced.

Comment: @inquirer sample DB have been uploaded. Gratefully with any feedback

Comment: @VanessaMiranda no need for screenshots, I need text data so I can copy it.

Comment: @inquirer new coder here, i believe the column name has been uploaded in text data

Comment: @anarchy look [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277716/how-can-i-create-a-table-in-a-post) how to add a table

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256039/discussion-between-inquirer-and-anarchy).

Comment: haha... i dont know how to put tables in stakoverflow! Sorry! *blush* i gave u the link to google collab

Comment: @anarchy replied in chat.